# char * printing out strange characters

Tags: c, string, file, strtok

I have a function that takes a `char ** const`as a parameter, and a file pointer. What I'm trying to do is in the file, if I SEE A LINE with white space, I’ll remove the "\r\n" characters from the line and store it in my variable. However, upon printing the variable out, I seem to be getting strange output.

The Textfile:

```
TestFILE
NUMBER
1
 whiteSpaceHere
 MoreWhiteSpace
```

..
As you can see, I have two lines that contain blatant whitespace.
And I have the functions (The reason I'm using const, and double pointers is because my project requires them (I'm not allowed to change function definitions)

```
int main(void) {
    char * temp;

    FILE * file = fopen("test.txt","r");
    if(file == NULL) { return 0; }

    testFunc(file, &temp);

    printOut(temp);

    return 0;
}

void testFunc(FILE * file, char ** const buffer) {
    char buf[256];

    *buffer = malloc(sizeof(buf));

    while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf,file) != NULL ) {
        if(isspace(buf[0]) {
            strtok(buf,"\r");
            strtok(buf,"\n");

            *buffer = buf;
        }

    }
}

//function to later free all alocated memory...
//void freeVars

void printOut(char * const print) {
    printf("The Value is %s\n,"print);

}
```

I'm trying to print it out here, to ensure the parsing works. I'm aware that it's a const variable, but I can't change that (This is just a snipit of my code) to test the parsing functionality. 
I tried to print out the buffer prior to the function call but that yielded the same result (Gibberish output).

I believe the issue might be with the NULL terminator, but I'm not sure how to go about approaching that. I'm told that the buffer passed, has to then contain a line (which had whitespace), and then has it's `"\r\n"` characters removed. I believe I've done that with strtok, however, I'm not sure why I'm getting strange output .

Comment: You allocated space for `buffer` but never used it and threw it away `*buffer = malloc(sizeof(buf));`, why? You then assigned the address of `buf` to `*buffer`. What do you think will happen when `buf` gets out of scope on function return? This address will be reclaimed. Where is `*buffer` pointing when control returns to main? Shouldn't you be using the allocated memory instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buf[]` is a local array to the function `testFunc`. It gets destroyed after the function returns. Accessing it after the function returns leads to undefined behavior.

---

**I tried to print out the buffer prior to the function call but that yielded the same result**

It will yield garbage, because at that point of time `temp` is not pointing to any allocated memory.

Comment: Well I can't have global variables, so how would I go about dealing with buf? I can't change the function parameters. Temp is malloced in the next function, is their a point of mallocing it twice then?

Comment: @ERDED: use `*buffer`, and drop `buf` - you don't need it.